# How to implement custom BindableProperty from XAML local:imageresource

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, embedded-resource, bindableproperty

(EDITED: clarity)

I want a `BindableProperty` for a custom control which will ultimately display an image. In my implementation (extracts below), the property `Source` gets assigned the value

```
Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource
```

instead of something resembling a path to the file.

My XAML has the following:

```
    <controls:StretchImage
      x:Name="Folder"
      HeightRequest="25"
      HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
      VerticalOptions="Center"
      BackgroundColor="Gold"
      Source="{local:ImageResource CloudTest.Assets.icons.folder_tab.png}" />
```

In StretchImage.cs I have:

```
class StretchImage : SKCanvasView
{
  public static readonly BindableProperty LabelProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Source), typeof(string), typeof(StretchImage),
                            null, Xamarin.Forms.BindingMode.OneWay);

  public string Source
  {
    get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
  }
}
```

What am I not understanding ?

Comment: resources and assets do not have file paths

Comment: ah, wrong type. do you happen to know the correct type ?

Comment: I assume you just want to use ImageSource

Comment: That looks like the right solution. I can't prove it till I write the rest of the code :) If you would post this as an answer, I'll credit you. Thanks.